# Pass char pointer to push_back vector of strings

Tags: c++

Is below code adding valid strings to the vector?

```
std::vector<std::string> Filesystem::getAllFiles(std::string name)
{
    std::vector<std::string> files;
    DIR *dirp = opendir(name.c_str());
    struct dirent *dp;
    while (NULL != (dp = readdir(dirp)))
    {
        files.push_back(dp->d_name);
    }
    closedir(dirp);
    return files;
}
```

Specifically: would `files.push_back(dp->d_name);` call the string constructor:

```
string (const char* s);
```

I am suspecting it will not, but would like to understand what will happen here, and why compiler is not complaining about it.

Comment: *I am suspecting it will not* -- Why did you suspect this?  This is how all classes work that have constructors that take the requisite argument type.  The compiler is smart enough to call the appropriate constructor. -- *and why compiler is not complaining about it.* -- because the compiler found the constructor that matches the type given.

Comment: This probably flies in the face of the assignment requirements, but if not, take advantage of [`<filesystem>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie because I got random exception sic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEE, yea I know this looks awkward but looks like exception from string allocator.

Comment: One of the best tools to pick off an unexpected exception is a debugger. Usually when the exception is thrown and not caught the debugger stops dead and lets you inspect the crash site. The actual bug may not be at the crash site, but there are always hints you can use to narrow down the location of the bug.

Comment: @MateuszWojtczak *because I got random exception* --  That means there is a bug in your code, and has nothing to do with how C++ selects constructors.   You should use the debugger to find out what is causing the exception by inspecting the call stack.  Also, you shouldn't approach problems like this thinking C++ is broken in some way.  For example, if you don't handle dynamic memory correctly, issuing a `delete` call can crash a program.  So do we say there is a bug in `delete`, or a bug in the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this code is fine <sup>1</sup>, and it will invoke the `std::string(const char*)` constructor as expected, since `dp->d_name` is a (null-terminated) `char[]` array that will *decay* into a `char*` pointer.

<sup>1: provided that `push_back()` does not raise an exception, otherwise the `DIR*` will be leaked.</sup>

Note that calling `push_back()` with a `char*` will make a temporary `std::string` that will have to be copied/moved into another `std::string` that is constructed internally by the vector.  In C++11 and later, you can use `emplace_back()` instead to avoid making that initial temporary:

```cpp
files.emplace_back(dp->d_name);
```